# onclick function fade in fade out content carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Evening,

i'm having trouble with onclick fade in and fade out animation on some content
this is the html script for the navigation:

```
<div class="col s12 m4">

    <h4 class="pict-menu"><a href="#!" id="type1" class="waves-effect waves-default">type1</a></h4>
    <h4 class="pict-menu"><a href="#!" id="type2" class="waves-effect waves-default">type2</a></h4>

</div>
```

and this is the content

```
<div class="col s12 m8 owl-carousel owl-theme" id="type-1">
    <?php foreach($regent as $row): ?>
    <div class="item"><img class="responsive-img" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/assets/images/media/<?php echo $row->media_file; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->media_title; ?>"></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<div class="col s12 m8 owl-carousel owl-theme" id="type-2">
    <div class="item"><img class="responsive-img" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/serenia/images/slide1.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="responsive-img" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/serenia/images/slide2.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

the javascripts

```
function type_click() {
    $("#type1").click(function() {
        $("#type-1").fadeIn(300);
        $("#type-2").fadeOut(300);
    });

    $("#type2").click(function() {
        $("#type-2").fadeIn(300);
        $("#type-1").fadeOut(300);
    });
}
$(function() {type_click()});
```

this is working fine when i'm just using 2 content, but it's not working properly when i tried to use more than 2 content. Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/y6xjuoba/

HTML

```
<div class="col s12 m4">

  <h4 class="pict-menu"><a href="#!" id="type-1" class="waves-effect waves-default">type1</a></h4>
  <h4 class="pict-menu"><a href="#!" id="type-2" class="waves-effect waves-default">type2</a></h4>
  <h4 class="pict-menu"><a href="#!" id="type-3" class="waves-effect waves-default">type3</a></h4>
  <h4 class="pict-menu"><a href="#!" id="type-4" class="waves-effect waves-default">type4</a></h4>

</div>



<div class="col s12 m8 owl-carousel owl-theme" id="type-2">
  <div class="item type-1">test1</div>
  <div class="item type-2">test2</div>
  <div class="item type-3">test3</div>
  <div class="item type-4">test4</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function type_click() {
  $(".waves-effect").click(function() {
    var clicked = $(this).hasClass("clicked")
    if (clicked !== true) {
      var currImage = '.' + $(this).attr("id"); + '"'
      $(".waves-effect").removeClass("clicked");
      $(this).addClass("clicked");

      $(".item").fadeOut(300);
      $(currImage).fadeIn(300);
    }

  });

}
$(function() {
  type_click()
});
```

It's kind of messy, but it should work for any number of images.  just make sure the class of the carousel item divs is equivalent to the id of the pict-menu links.  If you have a large number of images to carousel through you may want to consider some kind of templating solution like [Handlebars.](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Comment: Thank you so much! i wish i could give you more upvotes!

Comment: quick question tho, how can i load only 1 item? it seems you loaded all item on first page load. i've edited a bit of your jquery to add class on clicked item.. here https://jsfiddle.net/y6xjuoba/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".owl-theme").click(function() { //select by class
    var clicked  = $(this);
    clicked.fadeIn(300); //fade selected element in
    $('.owl-theme').not(clicked).fadeOut(300); //fade everything except clicked element out
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zkqf6mjz/

Comment: sorry, not working. please kindly check my edited question